# How to set the proper storage sizes for sleep and for hibernation?

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 7, how to set the proper storage sizes for sleep and for hibernation? Specifically, how much sizes and where to set up?

Comment: What do you mean by _storage_ sizes?

Comment: the upper limit size of the space on hard drive used to store the content of RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set a "proper" storage size for hibernation - during hibernation the entire contents of RAM is written to a file, `hiberfil.sys` and hence - the size will be equivalent to the home much physical RAM is available.

During sleep state, no data is written to hard disk( unless it's the newer "hybrid-sleep - in which case the above paragraph holds true).